# Выборка контактов из БД и отправка им почтовой рассылки

Tags: java

Мне необходимо сделать выборку из таблицы сотрудников, которые привязаны к определенной дате (ДД. ММ) и отправить почтовую рассылку другим сотрудникам, которые должны быть в курсе наступившей даты у сотрудников из первой выборки, с указанием ФИО этих сотрудников.

Работает все безукоризненно с одной деталью -- отправка происходит только на первую найденную почту. Но адресов в действительности много.

Что я сделала неправильно и как это исправить?

```java
List<String> listofChoosens;
List<String> listUsersAffected;
List<String> usertoSend;
List<String> fio;

public void sendMails(String day, String month) throws Exception {
    listofChoosens = choosenOneRepository.getCelebrantIds(day, month);// 1 шаг. Получить список всех сотрудников с определенной датой.
    System.out.println("Список первой выборки " + listofChoosens);
    for (int i=0; i<listofChoosens.size(); i++) {
        listUsersAffected = choosenOneRepository.select_affected_users(listofChoosens.get(i)); //2 Получить список связанных сотрудников с теми, кто отобран на шаге 1
        System.out.println("Список второй выборки " + listUsersAffected);
    }
    for (int j=0; j<listUsersAffected.size(); j++){
        usertoSend = contactsRepository.selects_email(listUsersAffected.get(j));// 3 получить почты сотрудников с шага 2
        System.out.println("мыло " + usertoSend);
        sendMail(usertoSend.get(j), "fio.get(j)");
    }
    for (int z=0; z<usertoSend.size(); z++){ // 4 получить имена сотрудников с шага 1
        fio = userRepository.selects_fio(listUsersAffected.get(z));
        sendMail(usertoSend.get(z), fio.get(z)); // 5 отправить рассылку на адреса, полученные на шаге 3, с указанием имен полученных на шаге 4
        System.out.println("ФИО " + "fio");
    }
}

public void sendMail(String mailAdress, String fio) throws Exception {
    mailSender.run(mailAdress, fio);
}
```

Comment: Вам же был дан ответ на аналогичный вопрос, который вы уже удалили [Как написать цикл, для использования результатов при отправке email?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1542202/)

Comment: Ответ неправильный. Решила сделать новую таску, где привела полную последовательность моих действий

Comment: Почему ответ неправильный?  Код "новой таски" содержит баг с переприсваиванием `listUsersAffected` и `usertoSend`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор не понимает код, который она написала, дублирует по сути один и тот же вопрос, игнорируя предоставленную ей помощь.

Comment: К тому же сохранился баг с получением ФИО по идентификаторам пользователей из _второй выборки_  `listUsersAffected`

Answer (score 0):

В представленном коде будет происходить **переприсваивание** значения `listUsersAffected` в первом цикле, то есть, код будет работать только для одного *последнего* значения из списка `listofChoosens`.

Второй цикл не имеет особого смысла -- он отправляет строку `"fio.get(j)"` и точно так же переприсваивает значение `userToSend`, используемое в следующем цикле:

```java
for (int j=0; j<listUsersAffected.size(); j++){
    usertoSend = contactsRepository.selects_email(listUsersAffected.get(j));// 3 получить почты сотрудников с шага 2
    System.out.println("мыло " + usertoSend);
    sendMail(usertoSend.get(j), "fio.get(j)");
}
```

*Повтор ответа из [удалённого вопроса: "Как написать цикл, для использования результатов при отправке email?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1542202/)*

---

Исходя из информации, представленной в вопросе, требуемую функцию отправки сообщений можно записать как-то так:

```java
public void sendMails(String day, String month) throws Exception {
    // шаг 1: listofChoosens
    List<String> celebrantIds = choosenOneRepository.getCelebrantIds(day, month); 

    for (String celebrant : celebrantIds) {
        // шаг 4: 
        List<String> fios = userRepository.selects_fio(celebrant);
        if (fios.isEmpty()) {
            // ни одно имя не найдено, пропускаем
            continue;
        }

        // шаг 2: listofAffected
        List<String> affectedUserIds = choosenOneRepository.select_affected_users(celebrant);

        for (String affectedId : affectedUserIds) {
            // шаг 3: полагаем, что емайлов может быть несколько
            List<String> emails = contactsRepository.selects_email(affectedId);

            for (String email : emails) {
                // шаг 5: отправка емайла только для _первого имени_
                 sendMail(email, "Важная дата для -  " + fios.get(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Применение циклов `for each` позволяет сократить код и избежать нежелательных выходов за пределы списка.

P.S. Даже если цикл отработает нормально, не факт, что для большого числа данных отправка всех сообщений будет успешной, или что отправка нескольких сотен сообщений одним и тем же получателям является полезной идеей.

Answer (score -1):

По этому фрагменту кода достаточно сложно понять, в чем именно прлоблема, но мне кажется, что вы просто перезатираете данные в цикле на каждой его итерации.
Попробуйте этот код и сравните со своей версий. Думаю, разберетесь:

```
public void sendMails(String day, String month) throws Exception {
    List<String> listofChoosens = choosenOneRepository.getCelebrantIds(day, month);// 1 шаг. Получить список всех сотрудников с определенной датой.
    List<String> listUsersAffected = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Список первой выборки " + listofChoosens);
    for (int i = 0; i < listofChoosens.size(); i++) {
        listUsersAffected.addAll(choosenOneRepository.select_affected_users(listofChoosens.get(i))); //2 Получить список связанных сотрудников с теми, кто отобран на шаге 1
        System.out.println("Список второй выборки " + listUsersAffected);
    }
    List<String> usertoSend = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < listUsersAffected.size(); j++) {
        usertoSend.addAll(contactsRepository.selects_email(listUsersAffected.get(j)));// 3 получить почты сотрудников с шага 2
        System.out.println("мыло " + usertoSend);
        sendMail(usertoSend.get(j), "fio.get(j)");
    }
    List<String> fio = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int z = 0; z < usertoSend.size(); z++) { // 4 получить имена сотрудников с шага 1
        fio.all(userRepository.selects_fio(listUsersAffected.get(z)));
        sendMail(usertoSend.get(z), fio.get(z)); // 5 отправить рассылку на адреса, полученные на шаге 3, с указанием имен полученных на шаге 4
        System.out.println("ФИО " + "fio");
    }
}

public void sendMail(String mailAdress, String fio) throws Exception {
    mailSender.run(mailAdress, fio);
}
```

Comment: -1 за кучу опечаток, в т.ч. и в _новом_ коде, за ложное утверждение  _достаточно сложно понять, в чем именно прлоблема_ так как на время написания ответа проблема была описана в комментарии и другом ответе, за скопированный баг с извлечением ФИО из авторского вопроса.